# Load impedance simulation of buck converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter, simulation, buck

I would like to design a buck converter that will feed a printed circuit board that contains an inductive load like a DC motor and a relay, and some capacitive circuits like RLC filter. I have started from designing the SMPS with a resistive load and the simulation using Simplis showed to me the buck is really robust. Than I have connected in parallel a DC motor model (an inductor with a series resistor), I performed many simulation by changing the value of the inductor and I have verified that my buck is stable till 100mH with a series resistance of 1ohm and a parallel resistive load of 1ohm. I have done the same thing for a capacitive load, by connecting a capacitor in series with ESR of 20m, so the converter is stable till C=550uf, than it starts to oscillate.

My objective now, is to study the effect of the load impedance (Inductive, capacitive, another DC-DC converter) on my DC-DC converter stability (The loop gain), I have tried to built an equivalent circuit to simulate the output impedance of the power supply with different load, but I have failed and my circuits do not generate a correct bode plot.

I undergo the book intitled "Switch mode power supplies -SPICE Simulation and practical design-",by CBASSO where the other explained deeply the effect of the input filter on input impedance of a buck converter, but I could not understand how the simulation is performed

Can anyone explain to me how to set a circuit that is feed by a voltage source from the input of a load and inject a current source at the output to get the impedance of a circuit ? (Using Simetrix/Simplis), because I think there are some tricks on how to set the circuit, inject a current source from one side and voltage source from another!

Comment: @verbalkint - this one's for you (in part).

Comment: Seems like a jumble of issues here-  The input filter issue was first studied by Middlebrook as far as I know, and the Middlebrook criterion gives a guideline for stability there.  Stability with load depends on the control scheme (voltage mode, current mode, hysteretic, etc.).  Then getting the impedance of a circuit in simulation can be done in SIMPLIS with the DVM module automatically, or by using an AC current source to sweep a current into the output and plotting voltage disturbance/input current.  We can wait for Chris to give the definitive answer though :)

Comment: @JohnD, you are absolutely right concerning the difference between "Stability with load and input filter", and my concern is the impact of load impedance to the loop gain. When I mentioned the impact of input filter impedance to the input SMPS impedance, because it is the only similarity that I have found concerning the study of influence of an impedance to another one. But I emphasize that my concern is the impact of load impedance to the converter stability. May be I will edit my question with some graphs and schematics to be more precise.